# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing, provisioning, provisioning-profile

This is the first time trying to test an app I created with LiveCode on an iPad.

I made sure that the IOS Provisioning Portal had the following set up as ad hoc:

```
certificates in Development and Distribution.
Ipad is registered
Apple ID is set up
provisioning in Development and Distribution.
```

When I try to get the app into Xcode the following error is displayed:

```
The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
```

How do I get all of this into xCode so my LiveCode app can be tested in the iPad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably, you used a distribution profile instead of a developer's profile.

The creation of the developer certificate and provision profiles are described step by step on Apple's website. I strongly recommend that you take your time to read these steps and to make sure that you follow each step correctly.

Apple's provision portal also has an assistant that helps you to create a developer's provision profile. You need to use this developer's provision profile instead of an ad-hoc prodile if you want to install your app through XCode on your own device(s).

You can use the devloper's profile in LiveCode's Standalone Application Settings window.

Comment: I tried it but still get the same error. Is there something I need to check in the portal? Maybe I'm not using the correct app id settings?

Comment: The app id isn't important when you're testing on your own device. The provisioning profile doesn't contain a reference to your app. The name of this profile is "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: \*". This includes the colon and the asterisk.The app id for this provisioning profile looks like "2AB4AX7EF10.\*", a 10-digit code plus a dot and an asterisk. The code is your team ID and the asterisk indicates that this profile can be used for any app, regardless of its ID. Make sure that you fill out all fields in LiveCode's Standalone Application Settings, including the bundle identifier.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I got it going. :-)

Comment: @Mark, why I can't use, production profile? I am aware that, I can't debug with production profile, but at least it should get install, isn't it?

Comment: For installation on your own device you need an ad hoc provision profile rather than a production profile. Production provision profiles can only be used for publishing apps in the store.

Answer (score 1):

This is a ENTITLEMENTS error, not a code sign issue.  Entitlements have to do with iCloud.  In Xcode 4 this was done on the Summary page at the bottom.  In Xcode 5 it is on a new page called capabilities at the top.  It will be lit up with a FIX this Issue Flag.  Simply select your Devel profile and you're good to go.  It does require an AppID set-up with iCloud Checked.   If you're not using iCloud simple delete whatever is in the Entitlements field in the build Settings.

Although I see the "read the doc" answers often. a.) Most of us do try to read the doc and b.) It rarely contains and useful granular detail needed to code or troubleshoot anything. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Entitlements are also used with the Game Center, Passbook, In-App Purchases and Maps.  All are setup in the Target Tab called Capabilities.