# Getting error, "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements" when installing on device

Tags: ios, xcode

This is my app entitlements on developer.apple.com

[image]

This is my Xcode's capabilities settings:

[image]

[image]

However the settings are matching to each other I'm getting following error.

This is my code signing section:

[image]

> **The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.**
>
> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

Xcode version: 7.1.1.
I've total three profiles

- Development (Debug)
- Production (AdHoc)
- Universal  (In House)

When I try to install with "Development" its installing without any error, but not with "Production" and (or) "Universal". I guess, I would never install with an "Universal" profile but with "Production" I should?.

Comment: You are likely to use a provisioning profile created without those capabilities. Can you also show us the **Code Signing** section in the build settings?

Comment: check this  link http://stackoverflow.com/a/14086304/5362916

Comment: @UmaMadhavi, I am able to install with `developer` profile, but not with production, what's the reason?

Comment: You can install with developer profile .

Comment: Yes, that's right. But what's the issue with `production` (by mean, "production" I meant, "ad hoc"...)? Hope we're onto the same track.

Comment: have u create adhoc distribution profile and new provisioning profile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625785/entitlements-file-do-not-match-those-specified-in-your-provisioning-profile-0xe

Comment: If I completely removed Code Signing Entitlements, then its working, but I'm not sure this is worth to do? @UmaMadhavi